# How to make customized alert in ionic 2?

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

Can you please tell me how to make a customized alert in ionic 2 ? like add image at top right corner make it clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these I always just create a custom modal page. You can full control all aspects of a modal, including sizing. It's basically just a page with a controller and template, super easy to implement too.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/ should get you all set

Answer (score 8):

We Can Use Modal Instead Of using Alert by Giving Padding to Modal.. Add Modal & Write This Code In App.scss :)

```
ion-modal {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    ion-content.content{
        top: 20%;
        left: 10%;

        width: 80%;
        height: 50%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        .scroll-content {
            border-radius: 20px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have it fit content size? So it doesn't stretch with the screen?

Comment: @Tadija Bagarić you can give background color Transparent so white background will not seen so your content is fit now :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using following to get the desired modal size.

```
.always-modal .modal-wrapper{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: unset !important;
    top: unset !important;
    .ion-page{
        margin:0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top:10%;
        width: 75%;
        height: 80%;
    }
}
```

Now whenever I need a modal with these properties I pass following in modal options.

```
{ cssClass: "always-modal" }
```

I am not able to figure out how to dismiss this modal when user taps on background area.

Comment: Is there a way to have it fit content size? So it doesn't stretch with the screen?

Comment: {showBackdrop: true, enableBackdropDismiss: true } will dismiss on clicking outside region